# Laravel Pagination Links not showing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-6

I used correct code but i don't know why links are not showing on view. i tried many solutions also but didn't work any.Can anyone help me to get out of this trouble?

**Controller**

```
public function show_all(){
        $all_records=DB::table('registrations')->paginate(3);

        return view('Admin.view_doctor',['all'=>$all_records]);
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="style">

            {{ $all->links() }}

 </div>
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Seems like you have less data in `registrations` table, that's why pagination links not showing.

Comment: Yes brother. Thanks for helping. Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this deserves a proper answer:

Laravel pagination HTML only shows when your data is greater than 1 page.

So for testing purposes, you could reduce your `perPage` number to a very low number, so multiple pages can be shown in the paginator:

```php
User::where('status', 1)->paginate(1);
```

Function definition:

```php
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
```